# HDFS Showing 0 Blocks after cluster reboot

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've setup a small cluster for testing / academic proposes, I have 3 nodes, one of which is acting both as namenode and datanode (and secondarynamenode).

I've uploaded 60GB of files (about 6.5 Million files) and uploads started to get really slow, so I read on the internet that I could stop the secondary namenode service on the main machine, at the moment it had no effect on anything.
After I rebooted all 3 computers, two of my datanodes show 0 blocks (despite showing disk usage in web interface) even with both namenodes services running.
One of the nodes with problem is the one running the namenode as well so I am guessing it is not a network problem.

any ideas on how can I get these blocks to be recognized again? (without start it all over again which took about two weeks to upload all)

---

## Update

After half an hour after another reboot this showed in the logs:

2018-03-01 08:22:50,212 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Unsuccessfully sent block report 0x199d1a180e357c12,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 0. The reports had 6656617 total blocks and used 0 RPC(s). This took 679 msec to generate and 94 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back no commands.
2018-03-01 08:22:50,212 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: IOException in offerService
java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is: "Warpcore/192.168.15.200"; destination host is: "warpcore":9000; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException

And the EOF stack trace, after searching the web I discovered this [http://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/CDH-5-5-0-datanode-failed-to-send-a-large-block-report/m-p/34420] but still can't understand how to fix this.
The report block is too big and need to be split, but I don't know how or where should I configure this. I´m googling...

Comment: What did you set dfs.namenode.name.dir and dfs.datanode.data.dir to?

Comment: I had it set to /home/hadoop/data/datanode
I changed it to /home/hadoop/data/datanode, /home/hadoop/data/datanode1, /home/hadoop/data/datanode2, /home/hadoop/data/datanode3 (....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be low RAM on my namenode, as a workaround I added more directories to the namenode configuration as if I had multiple disks and rebalanced the files manually as instructed ins the comments [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5153).
As hadoop 3.0 reports each disk separately the datenode was able to report and I was able to retrieve the files, this is an ugly workaround and not for production, but good enough for my academic purposes.
An interesting side effect was the datanode reporting multiple times the available disk space wich could lead into serious problems on production.
It seems a better solution is using HAR to reduce the number of blocks as described [here](http://hadoopinrealworld.com/hadoop-archives-har/) and [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/)